Is it potentially dangerous to run a bash script with sh?
So obviously when you run a Bash script with sh (as in sh ./path/to/bash-script.sh), you may experience errors in cases where sh is a symlink to a non-Bash shell that doesn't support a feature used in the script.
What I'm curious about is, if there could be a case where a script designed for Bash, executed by dash or some basic POSIX shell would cause code to be executed that otherwise definitely would not have been executed.
Everything I've tested (e.g. command grouping (( ... ))) simply causes the script to exit early when executed with a primitive POSIX shell, not causing any potential damage.

"Is it potentially dangerous to run a bash script"  Ending it there the answer will always be yes.  There are so many gotchas with shell scripting that even when you write and execute a script with the expected interpreter there is a very high likelihood for vulnerabilities, unless you are Stéphane.

The set of "Everything I've tested" will always be much, much smaller than the set of "Everything there is to test". No matter how you test, you can onnly approach perfection, the "No Known Errors" state.


Everything I've tested (e.g. command grouping (( ... ))) simply causes the script to script to exit early...

The ((...)) syntax is for arithmetic expressions, not command grouping.
I don't think errors like that will necessarily cause the script to exit early. It depends whether or not the expression is considered a syntax error (which will cause the shell to exit) or if it is simply interpreted as an invalid command. Consider something like this:
MYVAR=3

if (( MYVAR > 2 )); then
  echo "Do thing 1"
else
  echo "Do thing 2"
fi

If I run this script with bash, we see:
$ bash example.sh
Do thing 1

But if I run the script using a non-Bash shell, like dash, we see:
$ dash example.sh
example.sh: 3: MYVAR: not found
Do thing 2

Our attempt at using a bash-specific feature fails, but a failure does not cause the shell to exit; it simply continues and performs an action other than the expected one (in this case, it's because dash sees ((...)) as a nested subshell operator, so it's trying to execute MYVAR as a command). Additionally, the expression MYVAR > 2 will be interpreted as shell i/o redirection, so it will create or clobber the file named 2.
Is this "dangerous"? I'm not sure, but it can certainly lead to unexpected behavior.

As a second example, consider a script like this:
shopt -s nullglob

for x in *foo; do
  echo "$x"
done

The shopt command is bash-specific. Running this in bash (assuming you have no files matching the glob in your current directory) will produce no output.
Running this with dash produces:
example.sh: 1: shopt: not found
*foo

If you were using the result of that glob expression to create files, this could potentially result in dash creating invalid files, and could again trigger unexpected behavior in the script.

I don't have the answer you're looking for and I'm sure someone can come up with a few really interesting examples, but the answer to your question is absolutely yes.
As you mention running a bash script with a posix shell will likely result in several errors that will cause the code to execute in all sorts of ways you aren't expecting, and that can be very dangerous.  There are virtually infinite ways that executing else because of an unexpected error when you should have executed if could be considered "dangerous" to a production infrastructure.
A simple example:
$ cat shtest.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ a == a ]]; then
    echo bash
else
    echo dash
fi
$ ./shtest.sh
bash
$ dash ./shtest.sh
./shtest.sh: 3: [[: not found
dash

Sure you get an error but it's also still executing the code in the else statement.  What if it were:
if [[ $server == in_use ]]; then
    do_thing
else
    delete_server
fi


I think something you are looking for though is commands that would not error, something like brace expansion.
For example if you have a script that checks the health of lb_{1..3}, you might say if one fails spin up another lb server.  When run with dash it would interpret lb_{1..3} as a literal string instead of lb_1, lb_2, lb_3 and potentially spin up hundreds of unnecessary replacements.

First of all, you should be aware that even if your /bin/sh is a symlink to bash, that still causes problems because when called like that, bash runs in POSIX mode and doesn't support the full set of normal bash features. See the GNU bash documentation for a list of differences between normal bash and bash in POSIX mode.
That said, yes, it is absolutely possible that using dash to execute a bash script could result in executing something that would not have been executed if you had used bash. For example, what if you have an executable in your $PATH named [[? If your bash script has a [[ in it, since dash doesn't support [[, it will run that executable instead.
Here's a toy example (/home/terdon/scripts is in my $PATH):
$ cat scripts/foo.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

[[ 10 -gt 5 ]] && echo yes

Nice and simple and safe when run with bash, right?
$ foo.sh
yes

But here's the [[:
$ cat scripts/[[ 
#!/bin/sh
echo "gotcha!"

Now, if I run foo.sh with dash, I will actually execute the [[ file:
$ dash scripts/foo.sh
gotcha!
yes

What happens here is that dash will run the script [[ with the arguments 10, -gt, 5 and ]]. Since the [[ script I wrote ignores its arguments, that will run perfectly well and exit with a 0 status, so the && echo yes is also executed.
If [[ contained malicious code, even something as simple as rm -rf ~/*, I would have lost all of my files.

In short: Yes!
Basically it's like trying to compile a C++ program with a C compiler (however the compiler will complain before execution, while an interpreter like a shell will fail during execution): There is a common subset, but Bash has extensions a normal shell does not know about. It basically depends on the script.
You can check each script with a command like checkbashisms for compatibility issues.
See also Bashism.

What is the "Yes!" an answer to? The compiler example seems strange here, the issue isn't if there are differences between the shells, the question is specifically asking if it is possible that running the same script with dash would result in executing something that would not be executed with bash. If the shell fails, that isn't dangerous per se. The risk is that it often won't fail and instead do something unexpected.

"Yes" is the answer to the question "Is it potentially dangerous to run a bash script with sh?" - What did you think? Also it's the only question in the whole text!

Heh, fair, but the second paragraph, although not a question, as you correctly pointed out, seems to be the main point. In any case, a simple yes with no explanation isn't that useful. You seem to be implying that the danger is script failure but that isn't a danger, per se. It just means it wouldn't work.

@terdon IMHO the rest after the "Yes" is the explanation.
